# Query to find all days not available in a table

Tags: sql

I want to write a query for this problem:

> Show the days in August 1997 that no orders were placed.

I am able to find the days that orders were placed, but how can I find the days that no orders were placed?

This shows the day orders were placed:

```
SELECT
   o.OrderID,
   day(o.OrderDate) AS 'Date',
   sup.CompanyName 
FROM
   Orders o 
   INNER JOIN OrderDetails od ON o.OrderID = od.OrderID 
   INNER JOIN Products p ON od.ProductID = p.ProductID 
   INNER JOIN Suppliers sup ON p.SupplierID = sup.SupplierID 
WHERE
   sup.CompanyName = 'Tokyo Traders'
   AND o.OrderDate BETWEEN '1/1/1997' AND '1/31/1997'
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? PostgreSQL? Oracle? DB2?

Comment: @ErikE - Not really, the original post clearly stated `write a query to shows the day in august 1997 on which there were no any order placed`, which seems pretty copy-and-pasted from another source

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables you're right

Answer (score 2):

You'll need a Date table that you can join against to find the missing dates.

Assuming its SQL Server:

You can join your query against this to fetch results

```
WITH DatesTable
AS
(
  SELECT CAST('2007-08-01' as datetime) AS [date]
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATEADD(dd, 1, [date])
  FROM DatesTable
  WHERE DATEADD(dd, 1, [date]) <= '2007-08-31'
)
SELECT [date] FROM DatesTable
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Some thing similar to

```
WITH DatesTable
AS
(
  SELECT CAST('2007-08-01' as datetime) AS [date]
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATEADD(dd, 1, [date])
  FROM DatesTable
  WHERE DATEADD(dd, 1, [date]) <= '2007-08-31'
)
SELECT DT.[date]
FROM
   DatesTable DT 
   Left Outer Join Orders o on o.OrderDate = DT.[Date]

WHERE o.OrderDate is null

OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

The *cross-database* way to do this is to create a table that contains a row for each date, and then left join it to your detail table; the nulls are where there's no match.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming SQL Server:

```
WITH Dts AS (
   SELECT DateAdd(day, V.number, '19970801') Dt
   FROM master.dbo.spt_values V
   WHERE V.type = 'P'
   AND V BETWEEN 1 AND 31
)
SELECT Dts.Dt
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT *
   FROM
      Orders o 
      INNER JOIN Suppliers sup ON p.SupplierID = sup.SupplierID 
   WHERE
      sup.CompanyName = 'Tokyo Traders'
      AND Dts.Dt = o.OrderDat
)
```

I left in your condition on the CompanyName since I presume you want days that `Tokyo Traders` didn't place an order.